# Download audio file and save in Photo Library and finally play that audio

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I want to download audio file, save it in photos library and play after download. But this code not saving video in library.

Is it possible to download directly in photos library or any other folder externally.

My code is from here [Swift - Download a video from distant URL and save it in an photo album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479903/swift-download-a-video-from-distant-url-and-save-it-in-an-photo-album)

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if let url = URL(string: self.audioURL!),
            let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let filePath="\(documentsPath)/tempFile.mp3"
            print(filePath)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        print("Video is saved!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem

Comment: Is this downloading or not I don't know and where it is stored, it's not visible in photos.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save audio in the photos library, You can save it in the app folder and playing from here.

**Example:**

```
func saveAudioFile(url:URL){
    let docUrl: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let desURL = docUrl.appendingPathComponent("song.m4a") 

    var task: URLSessionDownloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self] (URLData, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let isFileExists: Bool? = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: desURL.path)
            if isFileExists == true{
                print(desURL)
            } else {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URLData!, to: desURL)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: thank you can we save in any other folder externally. it it possible.