# downloading video from url in Custom album in Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, photo

I am looking for the feature just like the Whatsapp has. They have an album named Whatsapp in iPhone Photos app and all the video and photos of whatsapp can be found there.

I have created the album with custom and also able to save image in it, but how can we download video from url directly into the folder ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Download a video from distant URL and save it in an photo album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479903/swift-download-a-video-from-distant-url-and-save-it-in-an-photo-album)

Comment: They are saving the video into Document, but I want to save my video to the album which I have created.... :(