# How to get video location playing by AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem, avplayerview

I am using AVPlayer to play the video from AWS CloudFront server. Here is my code:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

playerViewCont.player = player

present(playerViewCont, animated: false) { [weak self] in
    self?.playerViewCont.player?.play()
}
```

AVPlayer playing video from url every time its present. I want to save the video locally and for that I am seeking any function or way with which I can get downloaded video by AVPlayer so I can move it to another location for later use.

Any help?

Comment: hi, check this please ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479903/swift-download-a-video-from-distant-url-and-save-it-in-an-photo-album

Comment: I am looking to get path AVPlayer save its content for playing.. I have tons of video in my app like a Facebook feed so I can't let user  wait for its download..

Comment: it is relate to how do you save file. In the moment of save, you need to define a link. Like in the example below

Comment: I don't think you can touch the raw data managed by AVKit. So you may need to download it yourself. Or find another more efficient way to achieve your goal.

Comment: If I download a videos in chunks(Data), Is AVPlayer can play this?